# Compare struct char elements (not sure how to say it)

Tags: c, struct, comparison

I need to compare the contents of an element of a struct to another.

```
struct total_owners
    {
       int ADT2; //id number
       char arkyk[7]; //license plate number
    };

    typedef struct total_owners owners;

struct total_offenses
{
       char arkyk2[7];
       int serious; //seriousness of offense (0 or 1)
};

typedef struct total_offenses offenses;

struct total_drivers
{
       int ADT;
       int ADO; //license number
};

typedef struct total_drivers drivers;
```

what I want to compare is `arkyk2` in `total_offenses` with `arkyk` in `total_owners`. they are both of the format `XXX1234` ( three letters and 4 numbers)

this is the function I am working on

```
void sumpoints(offenses* b,owners* a, drivers* c, int amountowners , int amountoffenses ,int amountdrivers)
{
int totals[amountdrivers][3],i,j,h;
for (i=0;i<amountdrivers;i++)
{
    totals[i][0] = c[i].ADT;
    totals[i][1] = c[i].ADO;
    totals[i][2] = 0;
}

for (h=0;h<amountdrivers;h++)
{
    for (i=0;i<amountowners;i++)
    {   
        for(j=0;j<amountoffenses;j++)
        {
            if (a[i].arkyk == b[j].arkyk2) // this is wrong (definitely)
            {
                if (c[h].ADT == a[i].ADT2)
                {
                    totals[h][2] = totals[h][2]+1;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}   
for (i=0;i<amountdrivers;i++)
{
        printf("Total offenses per driver:\n");
        printf(" ADT %d \t ADO %d \t total %d\n", totals[i][0] , totals[i][1] , totals[i][2]);
}
}
```

the end result should be a totals array with the id number in the first column , the license number in the second and the amount of offenses in the last.

Comment: Have you looked as string functions like `strcmp` or `strncmp`?

Comment: @DanielDaranas is pointing out that "the question is missing from your question". It's probably something like "can you suggest the right way to do the comparison in the line that says …" or something like that. You might want to edit it accordingly.

Comment: the question was "how do i compare these 2". i didn't write it becuase i thought it was obvious.@DanielDaranas if you see something anyone do es wrong when posting don't be sarcastic ; just point out what he did wrong or downvote the "question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do string comparison, you would change

```
if ( a[i].arkyk == b[j].arkyk2 )
```

to

```
if( strncmp( a[i].arkyk, b[j].arkyk2, 7 ) == 0)
```

As was pointed out by @notlikethat, using plain `strcmp` may run into trouble since you have a 7 element array to store 7 characters, so there is no space for a terminating `'\0'`. By specifying that the comparison should stop after 7 characters, you avoid this issue.

Comment: Those are unterminated `char` arrays, not strings - `strcmp` will run off all over the place. You need `strncmp(a[i].arkyk, b[j].arkyk2, 7)`

Comment: @Notlikethat you are absolutely right, I had not paid close enough attention. I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

In C: Create a function called compare that takes the two different structures as parameters and returns a bool. Inside the function just do a string comparison with `strcmp or strncmp`

In C++:
Go nuts with operator overloading, it might look better, and will give you the same performance.